# How to sort particular list in sql

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting

Hi i am using this query to make the list of events

```
SELECT *, CASE
WHEN ((month > 9 OR (month =9 and days >= 22)) AND year <= 2012)then 'list1'
WHEN (year <= 2013) then 'list2' 
WHEN (year > 2013)then 'list3' 
end as sortlist from events order by sortlist, date
```

Now I want to sort the list3 by same sql, order by year. Is this possible?

Comment: could you clarify please - do you want to order by year only records when case = 'list3'?

Comment: ya i want to sort again only list3 order by year and keeping others is as it is.

Comment: I want to sort again list3 order by year ....

Comment: please refer this,it might help-
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645131/sql-case-statement-in-order-by-clause

Comment: I've added an answer, is it helpful for you?

Comment: Since you are doing this on a device, why not sort the lists in code ? That way you can constantly add features, massage lists, add weight to each item. The built in sort functions are super fast, less error prone. If you had only 1 list, doing the sort in sql is a no brainer, but when you make 3 lists, perhaps it might be better to do this in code

Comment: Doesn't the `date` already contain the year? What is the difference?

Comment: date was containing only the month and days in the format of MMDD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.
In order by, i just edited as

```
 order by sortlist, case when sortlist='list3' then year else null end,
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have SQL SERVER 2005 or higher you can do this

```
SELECT
    *,
    CALC.sortlist
from events as e
    outer apply
    (
        select
                case
                WHEN ((e.month > 9 OR (e.month =9 and e.days >= 22)) AND e.year <= 2012)then 'list1'
                WHEN (e.year <= 2013) then 'list2' 
                WHEN (e.year > 2013)then 'list3' 
            end as sortlist
    ) as CALC
order by
    CALC.sortlist, CALC.date,
    case when CALC.sortlist = 'list3' then e.year else null end
```

you can also do this, but it's not exactly ordering by year if your case equal 'list3' (I mean if you'll change expression in `case` you'll need to change `order by` as well)

```
SELECT
    *,
    case
        WHEN ((e.month > 9 OR (e.month =9 and e.days >= 22)) AND e.year <= 2012)then 'list1'
        WHEN (e.year <= 2013) then 'list2' 
        WHEN (e.year > 2013)then 'list3' 
    end as sortlist
from events as e
order by
    sortlist, e.date,
    case when e.year > 2013 then e.year else null end
```

Comment: if you want data to be sorte either by `date` or by `year`, you can write `order by sortlist, case when e.year > 2013 then e.year else date end`

Comment: what kind of SQL do you have?

Comment: using the query in android (sqlite) by java

Comment: well I don't know about sqlite, I could only suggest to try order like
`case when e.year > 2013 then e.year else 9999 end asc`