# ORDER BY with CASE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a dynamic order by statement.

Its purpose is to read a table of daily schedule overrides (0 to * records) and decide to use a global override or a store override, for selected day.

I thought of using a case clause like below but its not working as expected.

```
select * from schedule sdl 
where day = 3
and (sdl.store_id = 23331 or sdl.store_id is null)
order by
case when sdl.force is true 
then 'sdl.store_id nulls first' 
else 'sdl.store_id nulls last'
end 
limit 1
```

Is it possible to create an order-by statement using a case statement? Or maybe there is a better approach on the subject.

Comment: I think someone has answered this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645131/sql-case-statement-in-order-by-clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seemed to be on the right track. You just have to generate a value for each row and make it meaningful to how you want them sorted.

```
select  *
from    schedule sdl
where   day = 3
    and (sdl.store_id = 23331 or sdl.store_id is null)
order by case when sdl.store_id is null and sdl.force then 0 --nulls in front
             when sdl.store_id is null and not sdl.force then 2 --nulls in back
             else 1 end; --everything else in the middle
```

Tested on PostgreSQL 9.4.1

Comment: Just to contribute to your answer. If you want to get a different order for the middle results instead of else 1 -> else row_number() over (partition by primary_key_id order by primary_key_id desc) end

Comment: That would just "order" the rows in the same order they appeared in the result set. Just having the three values 0 for "Nulls first", 1 for "Non-nulls" and 2 for "Nulls last" provides more of a grouping effect, allowing for more order by criteria to provide sensible ordering within each group.

Comment: Not to mention that the value 2 could no longer be used for the "Nulls last" group. You would have to keep track somehow of the number of generated row numbers and set it to some value greater than the number of the last row.

Comment: I mean I tested it and its working. What I want to achieve is if no null values exist, then sort the non-null values by last inserted desc and take the first one. Like priority to the last non-null inserted override.

Comment: You can do the same thing with `order by case ... end, primary_key_id`. This would work with before and after nulls, only before nulls, only after nulls and no nulls at all.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible, the link in the comment to your question shows a valid example but it looks like your issue is
"nulls first/last". These aren't valid postgres constructs. Your query should be like

```
select * from schedule sdl
where day = 3 and (sdl.store_id = 23331 or sdl.store_id is null)
order by
case when sdl.force is true
     then sdl.store_id end desc,   
case when sdl.force is false  
     then sdl.store_id end         
limit 1
```

asc is default sorting (doesn't need to be specified explicitly)

Answer (score -2):

Try to use the case in the select clause and then sort by that field.

Without testing I should look something like that

```
select *, 
case when sdl.force is true 
  then 'sdl.store_id nulls first' 
  else 'sdl.store_id nulls last'
  end as orderfield 
from schedule sdl 
where day = 3
and (sdl.store_id = 23331 or sdl.store_id is null)
order by orderfield
limit 1
```

Comment: I don't think that this is valid. 'sdl.store_id nulls first'::text thus it is interpreted to text and not the actual store_id reference

Comment: oh yes is see I forget the nulls first and nulls last. sorry